# How can I output the content of a [ADV] file with the cat command in the console?

Tags: bash

I have a folder with files, would like to output the contents of the individual files in a loop, but it doesn't work.
Unfortunately, the name is not given.

What I tried:

```
cat \[ADV]\ ...
```

But it doesn't work.

If I change the filename for example `ABC` then it works. What am I doing wrong?

Examples of files:

```
[ADV] DFN-CERT-2018-0399 PHP- Eine Schwachstelle ermöglicht einen Denial-of-Service-Angriff.eml
[ADV] DFN-CERT-2018-0409 PostgreSQL- Eine Schwachstelle ermöglicht die Eskalation von Privilegien.eml [ADV] 
DFN-CERT-2018-0422 Tor- Zwei Schwachstellen ermöglichen Denial-of-Service-Angriffe.eml
```

Comment: i solve the problem with : cat \[ADV\]\ DFN-CERT-2018-0422\ Tor-\ Zwei\ Schwachstellen\ ermöglichen\ Denial-of-Service-Angriffe.eml but how can i do this in a loop ?

Comment: `cat '[ADV]'*`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the literal parts of the filename inside quotes, while keeping the `*` (the *intended* glob character) unquoted. Thus:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in '[ADV] '*.eml; do
    echo "FILE = ${file}:"
    cat <"${file}"
    echo
done
```

...this prevents `[ADV]` from being treated as a glob expression that matches exactly one character, either `A`, `D` or `V`, which would be its meaning when unquoted.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work as a FOR/DO LOOP.

```
#!/bin/bash
MY_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")

for file in `ls \[ADV\]\ *.eml`; do
    echo "FILE = ${file}:"; cat "${file}";
    echo;
done
IFS=$MY_IFS
```

The [IFS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184867/186861) adjustment is needed because of spaces/escapes in your filenames. Note: There are many ways of doing this. FIND+READ/WHILE would probably be better choice, generally. But, this will work from CWD. More on IFS [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9499/186861).

Output will look like this:

[image: Loop Results]